# Renaming and resetting Chapter in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have two questions in LaTeX:

1. How to reset the chapter counter to 1 or to set it to any other number?
2. How to rename Chapter 1 to Paper A? To rename it to Paper 1, I have this solution:

   ```
   \renewcommand\chaptername{Paper}
   ```

The first chapter then becomes Paper 1. But I can't get to rename 1 to A so as to get Paper A.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is from memory, but for the first:

```
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
```

And for the second:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Paper}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I guess that you have seen that you inadvertently typed \Alpha for \Alph.

Comment: Works like a charm and can easily be adapted

Comment: First point only works on first sight. It confuses the hyperref package and breaks all links (ref and toc).

Comment: For the section, one may use: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`

Answer (score 5):

For the first:

```
\setcounter {chapter} {1}
```

For the second, try using `\Alph` - this might work:

```
\setcounter {chapter} {\Alph{1}}
```

See [this](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/07/25/counters-in-latex/).

Comment: You're welcome - half the problem with LaTeX is that you either know the answer or you don't - I really struggle with it from time to time but still love it to bits :)

Comment: I can't think to not work with LaTeX for typing big documents. The good thing with LaTeX is that there's usually more than one way to arrive at a solution. This really helps the user to become creative. It's hard to know everything in LaTeX. Using it is a lifelong learning adventure...